# Splitting ndarray gives unexpected results (TensorFlow RNN tutorial)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am following a [tutorial](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html) on rnn's in TensorFlow but I have a question concerning the input formats.

They are taking raw_x (one hot vector) and basically first cutting that up in pieces of length 200 (batch_size) to form data_x. That is good.

Then they further cut up data_x in pieces of length 5 (num_step, or graph width) with:

```
for i in range(epoch_size):  
    x = data_x[:, i * num_steps:(i + 1) * num_steps]
    y = data_y[:, i * num_steps:(i + 1) * num_steps]
    yield (x, y)
```

However, if I look in the data, the slices of x do not match data_x. The first one does, but then they diverge.

Am I misunderstanding the above code? I would like to understand how x is being created or what it is supposed to look like.

[image]

[image]

I had expected the second item to be 0 1 0 1 0.

Also, I thought an epoch is when you go through the data completely, from this it seems that they split up the data in 1000 parts (epoch size)?

If it helps, this is my full code. I am trying to figure out what is going on in x. at line 48:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# %matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Global config variables
num_steps = 5 # number of truncated backprop steps ('n' in the discussion above)
batch_size = 200
num_classes = 2
state_size = 4
learning_rate = 0.1

def gen_data(size=1000000):
    print('generating data');
    X = np.array(np.random.choice(2, size=(size,)))
    Y = []
    for i in range(size):
        threshold = 0.5
        if X[i-3] == 1:
            threshold += 0.5
        if X[i-8] == 1:
            threshold -= 0.25
        if np.random.rand() > threshold:
            Y.append(0)
        else:
            Y.append(1)
    return X, np.array(Y)

# adapted from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py
def gen_batch(raw_data, batch_size, num_steps):
    print('generating batches');
    raw_x, raw_y = raw_data
    data_length = len(raw_x)

    # partition raw data into batches and stack them vertically in a data matrix
    batch_partition_length = data_length // batch_size
    data_x = np.zeros([batch_size, batch_partition_length], dtype=np.int32)
    data_y = np.zeros([batch_size, batch_partition_length], dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(batch_size):
        data_x[i] = raw_x[batch_partition_length * i:batch_partition_length * (i + 1)]
        data_y[i] = raw_y[batch_partition_length * i:batch_partition_length * (i + 1)]
    # further divide batch partitions into num_steps for truncated backprop
    epoch_size = batch_partition_length // num_steps

    for i in range(epoch_size):
        x = data_x[:, i * num_steps:(i + 1) * num_steps]
        y = data_y[:, i * num_steps:(i + 1) * num_steps]
        yield (x, y)

def gen_epochs(n, num_steps):
    for i in range(n):
        yield gen_batch(gen_data(), batch_size, num_steps)


"""
Placeholders
"""

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])

"""
RNN Inputs
"""

# Turn our x placeholder into a list of one-hot tensors:
# rnn_inputs is a list of num_steps tensors with shape [batch_size, num_classes]
x_one_hot = tf.one_hot(x, num_classes)
rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(x_one_hot, axis=1)
"""
Definition of rnn_cell

This is very similar to the __call__ method on Tensorflow's BasicRNNCell. See:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py
"""
with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

def rnn_cell(rnn_input, state):
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell', reuse=True):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    return tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf.concat(axis=1, values=[rnn_input, state]), W) + b)
"""
Adding rnn_cells to graph

This is a simplified version of the "rnn" function from Tensorflow's api. See:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py
"""
state = init_state
rnn_outputs = []
for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
    state = rnn_cell(rnn_input, state)
    rnn_outputs.append(state)
final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]
"""
Predictions, loss, training step

Losses and total_loss are simlar to the "sequence_loss_by_example" and "sequence_loss"
functions, respectively, from Tensorflow's api. See:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py
"""

#logits and predictions
with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
logits = [tf.matmul(rnn_output, W) + b for rnn_output in rnn_outputs]
predictions = [tf.nn.softmax(logit) for logit in logits]

# Turn our y placeholder into a list labels
y_as_list = [tf.squeeze(i, axis=[1]) for i in tf.split(axis=1, num_or_size_splits=num_steps, value=y)]

#losses and train_step
losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit,labels=label) for \
          logit, label in zip(logits, y_as_list)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)
"""
Function to train the network
"""

def train_network(num_epochs, num_steps, state_size=4, verbose=True):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        training_losses = []
        for idx, epoch in enumerate(gen_epochs(num_epochs, num_steps)):
            training_loss = 0
            training_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))
            if verbose:
                print("\nEPOCH", idx)
            for step, (X, Y) in enumerate(epoch):
                tr_losses, training_loss_, training_state, _ = \
                    sess.run([losses,
                              total_loss,
                              final_state,
                              train_step],
                                  feed_dict={x:X, y:Y, init_state:training_state})
                training_loss += training_loss_
                if step % 100 == 0 and step > 0:
                    if verbose:
                        print("Average loss at step", step,
                              "for last 250 steps:", training_loss/100)
                    training_losses.append(training_loss/100)
                    training_loss = 0

    return training_losses

training_losses = train_network(1,num_steps)
plt.plot(training_losses)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the batches are actually transposed.

So the first elements of the x-matrix (200 x 5) will fit the first 5 elements of x_raw.

Then only in the next iteration, the next 5-10 elements of x_raw will be in the first elements (again) of x.